# Is there an integer solution for $(x^x) + (y^y) =(z^z)?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there an integer solution for $x^x + y^y =z^z?$
Is there an  approach to evaluate that if this question has a Yes or no answer.
Computers are useless as figures become so big after few iteration.

Comment: Note that the answers in the duplicate problem doesn't deal with the negative integer cases.

Comment: If $x,y,z$ have a common factor $>2$, then the equation becomes an example of Fermat's Last Theorem and has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no solution. The intuitive proof is to look at the sequence $a_n=n^n$ and observe that the gap between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is much bigger than $a_n$, so you can’t add something smaller than $a_n$ and get $a_{n+1}$. This can be proven more formally by contradiction:
Assume that we have 3 positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^x+y^y=z^z$. Then clearly z>x and z>y, so z-1 is greater than or equal to both y and x. If z were less than 3, our solution could easily have been found in your computer search, so we may assume z>2.

Thus we have $$z^z=z(z^{z-1})>2(z^{z-1})>2(z-1)^{z-1} \geq x^x+y^y$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: You are assuming that all of the integers are positive. Note that $ (-3)^{-3}  + (-2)^{-2} > (-1)^{-1}$.